# Is it possible to debug a Windows Store app on Surface RT (or other ARM devices running Windows RT)？

Tags: debugging, windows-store-apps, windows-rt

I have known that Surface RT version can only run Windows Store app. So, Can I deploy my own Windows Store app to Surface RT and debug it by Visual Studio 2012 remote debugger?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This Microsoft document](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30703) says you can use remote debugging.

Comment: The link says, "We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found."